# how to import variable product in woocommerce without using pro plugins

Tags: woocommerce, import, product-variations

Normal import does not import variation in variable product

A free plugin which import variable product OR An alternative solution such as a Code that allow import Variable product properly
I Need a perfect solution without using a paid version

Answer (score 0):

if you need it for one or several times import, you can use store manager for woocommerce, it has flexible import functionality for variations

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).